# Correct way to handle PLSQL exceptions in Java

Tags: java, plsql

I have a query regarding PLSQL exceptions and how to handle them in Java .I have some Stored procedures which upon some exception uses "dbms_output.put_line" to print the error messages. As I can't get these messages in my java "front-end", How should I modify my Stored procedures to get these exceptions?

I can think about two ways but I don't know if these are correct and if they are used in projects.

- Use an OUT parameter to send this error message to Java, if the SP
  executes successfully then it will be "null", but in-case some
  exceptions occurs I will populate this with an error message from my PLSQL EXCEPTION block.
- RAISE the exception form PLSQL Exception block so I can get the
  exception using try-catch block of Java as SQLException

Maybe there is some better way which I do not know about.. Kindly suggest me how should I proceed in such situations.

---

**TLDR :**
How to code PLSQL Exception block so I can handle it in Java. The actual way used in real projects by professionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> RAISE the exception form PLSQL Exception block so I can get the
>   exception using try-catch block of Java as SQLException

Better way ... Follow this way .

Comment: If using spring you can map the plsql exceptions to java exceptions.

Comment: @FinalFive I am not using spring, but its good to know that spring has such option. thanks